checkov to scan aws. cdk ts files
Hi just checking if anyone from you have already tried to scan the aws cdk typescripts using checkov via github actions? I understand that for the chekcov to perform scan it needs 1st to do cdk synth then scan the template.json files located on cdk.out folder. Howeve I think it is not covered on their provided github-actions integration page.
